# Android Studio - File is read only

Tags: java, android

I've downloaded a library from github and I would like to edit the class to suit my needs. But Android Studio won't allow me saying "File is read only" when I try to type and edit the class.

[image: linked image so you can see what I mean]

Comment: It's in a JAR. You can't edit JARs.

Comment: What do I do to edit the class then?

Comment: You need to download the actual source code and edit it, then include that. Look up how to add modules to Android Studio.

Answer (score 4):

I think, the file is locked as READ-ONLY.

[image]

You can click on the lock icon to toggle the READ-ONLY Option.The option can be found at the BOTTOM-RIGHT Corner of the Android Studio.

Comment: You can find a tutorial on this approach here: https://youtu.be/nx43-77cyaM

Answer (score 1):

I used Mac OS X and coded used Flutter:

after I didn't see the file explorer on the right side. I went to:

Project Structure -> Modules -> '+' -> APK -> Apply.

Then all files were shown in read-only mode, I don't know why.

Then I deleted the `.idea` folder in the root folder and it returned to normal(in Mac OS X: press CMD + Shift + '.' to show hidden files)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Go to the file in the Windows explorer and make an rightclick and then click on properties. Uncheck write protect! If this not function try to start Andruid Studio as adminstrator.

Comment: That file is not supposed to be modified instead he can extend if it is not final and override behaviors if permitted otherwise, clone the source code and this new edited code ad dependency and remove existing one.

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote this answer, it was actually what happened to me, `cmd+i` on the file jumps to the finder and again info `cmd+i` and it was read-only, IDK why thought

Comment: Unfortunately this does not fix the issue in my case.  My files are not locked read-only by the OS.  The error is inside Android Studio in some context.

Comment: yes this solution fixed my issue . thankyou @scolastico

Answer (score -1):

- Close Android Studio.
- Save .idea folder for future restore (if something happend)
- Remove .idea folder
- Start Android Studio and open project.